# JS how to createElement and appendchild in one step theory?

Tags: javascript, appendchild, createelement

To be clear I am looking for an explanation on how creating an element and text node in one-line without declaring variables work. Why does .parentNode need to be used and how come the result is just the data and no p tag without using .parentNode?

```
const element_posts = document.getElementById("myPosts");

element_posts.appendChild(document.createElement("p").appendChild(document.createTextNode(data)).parentNode);
```

Working normal code that functions as expected, it prints out data inside a p tag

```
const element_posts = document.getElementById("myPosts");

const contentParagraph = document.createElement("p");
const contentTextNode = document.createTextNode(data);
contentParagraph.appendChild(contentTextNode);
element_posts.appendChild(contentParagraph);
```

Also working code but in one line

```
const element_posts = document.getElementById("myPosts");

element_posts.appendChild(document.createElement("p").appendChild(document.createTextNode(data)).parentNode);
```

The code outputs a p tag with data inside, but I am asking about the theory of doing it in one line.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not, the P is ignored

```js
document.getElementById("myPosts1")
  .appendChild(
    document.createElement("p") // returns a p element
      .appendChild(document
        .createTextNode("data") // returns a textnode
      ).parentNode // returns the textNode's parentNode, i.e. the P
    );
    
document.getElementById("myPosts2")
  .appendChild(
    document.createElement("p") // returns a p element but is ignored
      .appendChild(document
        .createTextNode("data") // returns a textnode which is appended
      )
    );
```

```css
#myPosts1 { border: 1px solid black; }
#myPosts2 { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<div id="myPosts1"></div>
<div id="myPosts2"></div>
```

Comment: yep, great demonstration